Skew symmetric $1$-form $\beta$ must be zero if $\beta \wedge \omega = 0$
Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on a manifold $M$ and $U\subset M$. I have that $\omega = f^{-1}\eta$ where $\eta:TU\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $g$-orthonormal, i.e. $g|_{TU} = \eta^T\eta = \eta_1^2 + ... + \eta_n^2$, and $f:U\to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is smooth. I want to show that if $\beta$ is $1$-form taking values in $\mathfrak{o}(n)$, i.e. $\beta^T = -\beta$, and satisfies the equation $\beta\wedge \omega=0$ then it must be that $\beta=0$. I was trying to use the fact that $\eta^T\eta>0$ somewhere by maybe taking a product of $\beta\wedge \omega$ with $(\beta\wedge \omega)^T$ but the terms don't align well (I get $\eta$ $\eta^T$ instead, which is a matrix).
Any help is appreciated.

I believe all you need to know is that $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n$ are linearly independent $1$-forms. Write $\beta = [\beta_{ij}]$. Your hypothesis is that $\sum\limits_j \beta_{ij}\wedge\omega_j = 0$ for all $i$. Since the $\omega_j$ are linearly independent, the Cartan lemma tells us that
$$\beta_{ij} = \sum_k c_{ijk}\omega_k,\quad\text{where } c_{ijk} = c_{ikj}.$$
But your skew-symmetry hypothesis on $\beta$ tells us that $c_{ijk} = -c_{jik}$. It is now a standard manipulation (which can be stated fancily in terms of group representations) to see that $c_{ijk} = 0$ for all $i,j,k$:
$$c_{ijk} = -c_{jik} = -c_{jki} = c_{kji} = c_{kij} = -c_{ikj} = -c_{ijk}.$$

Thank you for your clear, concise answer. I don't know why I didn't think of using Cartan's Lemma.
